# Catching distinct errors in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an Angular's HTTP interceptor. Application uses RxJS timer to send requests (short polling). Every 5s it sends around 10 requests. I want to use the interceptor to handle 502-504 status codes. I know how to catch errors, but the problem is polling.

Once I send 10 requests, I get 10 errors almost in the same time. I would like to `distinctUntilChanged()` or at least `take(1)` somehow, but both things does not work together with `catchError()`.

```js
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly store: Store<AppState>) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<string>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<string>> {
        const errorCodes = [502, 503, 504];

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            // take(1),
            // distinctUntilChanged(), // both lines not working, because error is thrown earlier
            catchError(err => {
                if (errorCodes.includes(err.status)) this.store.dispatch(connectionLost());

                return throwError(err);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

I know I could dispatch a new action about the error and use `distinctUntilChanged` in its effect. But I will get this action dispatched 10 times in Redux DevTools. I would like to avoid that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider using `materialize()` and `dematerialize()` ? Using `materialze()` you can _supress_ incoming errors and send them as `error notifications`(not errors per se) and then you could provide a custom `compare` fn to `distinctUntilChanged`.

Comment: Didn't know about these operators. Thanks! :) Can you convert your comment into answer? I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `materialize()` and `dematerialize()`.  Using `materialize()` you can suppress incoming errors and send them as **error notifications**(**not** errors per se) and then you could provide a custom `compare` fn to `distinctUntilChanged`.

```js
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  /* ... */
  materialize(), // Convert into notification
  distinctUntilChanged(yourCustomFn),
  /* ... */
  dematerialize() // Get back the `original value`
  /* ... */
);
```